How to pivot result table SQL
I have the follwing T-SQL statement:
SELECT *, YEAR(STARTDATE) AS YEAR
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = 3438

The result is this:



ID
STARTDATE
VOLUME
YEAR




3438
01-01-2025
1000
2025


3438
01-01-2026
1000
2026


3438
01-01-2027
1000
2027



I would like to produce the following result:



ID
2025
2026
2027




3438
1000
1000
1000



I tried to use the function PIVOT, but I can't seem to make that work.

Do you need this query to be dynamic?  In other words, do you want the solution to also work for 2024 or 2028 without modifying the query?

Please correct your data or result. Row 2 startdate is invalid. Maybe you meant 2026. Row 3 ID is 3848. Maybe you meant 3438.

thank you Bart. You are right. The data in the table is incorrect. I will correct it and try your solution. And yes, it needs to be dynamic.

Dynamic pivot in SQL is a code-smell / anti-pattern. Use normalised data inside SQL, then if you need to rotate it for use outside of the database, do that outside of the database.

You can use GROUP BY and use a CASE expression with an aggregation (MIN, MAX or SUM would work in this case) to do this:
SELECT 
  ID, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(STARTDATE) = 2025 THEN VOLUME END) AS VOLUME_2025, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(STARTDATE) = 2026 THEN VOLUME END) AS VOLUME_2026, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(STARTDATE) = 2027 THEN VOLUME END) AS VOLUME_2027
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID = 3438
GROUP BY ID


Thank you VvdL,
This works for the simple dataset. But the real dataset is more complex. I will keep you posted about the results.

Here is a dynamic pivot solution
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[YEAR]) 
            FROM TABLE c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
    
set @query = 'SELECT ID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select ID
                    , VOLUME
                    , [YEAR]
                from TABLE
                WHERE  ID = 3438
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(VOLUME)
                for [YEAR] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

